# What's the most efficient way to mow a lawn?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, numerical-methods, asymptotics

For $S\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ and $x\in\Bbb R$, define $E_x(S)=\{y\in\Bbb R^2:d(y,S)<x\}$. ($E_x(S)$ represents the expansion of $S$ by $x$.) Given a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$, denote its length as $L(\gamma)=\int_\gamma|dx|\in[0,\infty]$ (for non-rectifiable paths, $L(\gamma)=\infty$).

Assume now that $S$ is connected and bounded, and let $$\lambda_\epsilon=\inf\Big\{L(\gamma):E_1(S)\subseteq \overline{E_1(\gamma)}\subseteq \overline{E_{1+\epsilon}(S)}\Big\}.$$ This is our best path for a lawnmower with cutting radius $1$ to mow the lawn $E_1(S)$ with an overspill of at most $\epsilon$. The questions are:

- Does $\lambda_\epsilon$ exist for every $\epsilon>0$? (I think I can prove this.)
- Does $\lambda_0$ exist? (Not sure about this.)
- Is $\lambda_\epsilon$ a minimum in either case, i.e. is there an acceptable path whose length is $\lambda_\epsilon$?
- Are there any algorithms for finding paths whose lengths are within $\delta$ of $\lambda_\epsilon$? (I'm not sure how to make this precise.)

This is what I'm thinking about every time I mow my lawn, and I bet I'm not alone.

**Edit:** A proof for the first question: Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $S$ is bounded, so is $E_{\epsilon/2}(S)$, and it is also totally bounded. Therefore, there is a finite cover $(B(\epsilon/2,x_k))_{k=1}^n$ of $E_{\epsilon/2}(S)$ by balls of radius $\epsilon/2$. Since $E_{\epsilon/2}(S)$ is a union of open connected sets, which are connected together by $S$, it is also connected. Now any open connected set is path-connected by polygonal paths, so there is a polygonal path from $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$ for every $1\le i<n$. The concatenation of these is a polygonal path $\gamma$ which passes through each $x_i$ and remains in $\bigcup_{k=1}^nB(\epsilon/2,x_k)\subseteq E_{\epsilon}(S)$. Then $E_1(\gamma)\subseteq E_{1+\epsilon}(S)$, and any point in $E_1(S)$ is within $1-\epsilon/2$ of a point in $E_{\epsilon/2}(S)$, which is within $\epsilon/2$ of some $x_k\in\gamma$, so $E_1(S)\subseteq E_1(\gamma)$. Finally, since $\gamma$ is polygonal, it is rectifiable, so $\lambda_\epsilon\le L(\gamma)$ and $\lambda_\epsilon$ exists.

If you consider the linear paths from $x_i$ to $x_j$ when the balls $B(\epsilon/2,x_i)$ and $B(\epsilon/2,x_j)$ are not disjoint, you get a graph on $n$ vertices, and the problem of finding the shortest path on this graph that visits all the vertices is exactly the Traveling Salesman Problem. Thus this does not bode well for efficient algorithms to solve this problem.

Comment: I usually think about someone doing it for me...

Comment: @Eleven Actually, I don't own my own house yet, but questions like these are why I'm getting a condo instead.

Comment: Haha... Mario, I'm currently looking out my window at a LOT of long grass, hoping my neighbor gets mad and does it for me... Good idea with the condo!

Comment: I don't see why in your definition you require the (expansion of the) lawnmower's path to contain $E_1(S)$. Surely you just want to mow the grass in $S$, so the path just needs to contain $S$. I would require it to contain $S$, and be contained in $E_\epsilon(S)$.

Comment: @JackM In this model, the "lawn" is $E_1(S)$, not $S$. In fact the set $S$ is never used directly - it could be reformulated in terms of a set $A$ which is $E_1$ of some set. The reason for this circuity is because my lawnmower is circular, and I want to avoid lawns that are too "pointy" to be mowed without a significant amount of overspill. (For example, there are no paths that mow the unit square without at least $1-1/\sqrt2$ of overspill.)

Comment: I'd conjecture that following the Hilbert space-filling curve would be the most efficient way.

Comment: @Igor It's not necessary for the path itself to cover $E_1(S)$, just its expansion by radius $1$ - i.e. you would need a really tiny lawnmower for this to be necessary. Furthermore, any such curve will necessarily be non-rectifiable, and so would not be close to efficient. Lastly, what do you do in there is a tree (i.e. a hole) in the lawn? Answers based on a fixed curve would have to adapt to irregularities in the shape of the border, and my experience with actual lawnmower tells me that this is the hard part.

Comment: What a great question...

Comment: Another cool problem would be if we forget the "overspill", and still would be applicable to lawn grass cutting, that could be interesting too!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is nicer with closed-disc lawnmowers, so let me define $D_x(S) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^2 | d(y,S) \leq x\}$, and define $\mu_{\epsilon}$ as: 
$$ \mu_{\epsilon} = \inf\left\{L(\gamma) | D_{1}(S) \subseteq D_1(\gamma) \subseteq \overline{D_{1+\epsilon}(S)}\right\} $$
If $\epsilon>0$, I think your existence proof works the same for $\mu_{\epsilon}$. Below I prove the infimum can be achieved when using these closed-disc mowers.  I also give a possible counter-example for open-disc mowers.

---

Fix $\epsilon\geq 0$ and assume $\mu_{\epsilon}$ exists and is positive.  Let $\gamma_n(t)$ be an infinite sequence of rectifiable paths with the property $D_1(S) \subseteq D_1(\gamma_n) \subseteq \overline{D_{1+\epsilon}(S)}$,  and such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} L(\gamma_n) = \mu_{\epsilon}$.  We can assume each path $\gamma_n$ is defined to traverse its course at constant speed of $L(\gamma_n)$ distance/time (see below comment of Mario for further justification of this assumption). So for $0 \leq t \leq 1$, $\gamma_n(t)$ is the point on the path that is a fraction $t$ of the total distance of the path. For all $n$ and all $t, v \in [0,1]$ we have:

$$  ||\gamma_n(t)-\gamma_n(v)|| \leq |t-v|L(\gamma_n)  $$

(see Note 1 for more detail on this). Furthermore, the paths $\gamma_n(t)$ are all contained in a bounded region of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\{q_1, q_2, \ldots\}$ be a listing of rationals in $[0,1]$.  By the diagonalization lemma in the Appendix of *Probability and Measure* by Billingsley, there is a subsequence $n_k$ such that $\gamma_{n_k}(q_i)$ converges for all $i$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$ (this is essentially a countably-infinite extension of the Bolzano-Wierstrass theorem). Let $\gamma(q_i)$ be the limiting value, defined for each rational $q_i$.

The function $\gamma(q_i)$ is continuous over the rationals because for any two rationals $q_i, q_j$ in the interval $[0,1]$ we have:

\begin{align}||\gamma(q_i)-\gamma(q_j)||&\leq ||\gamma(q_i)-\gamma_{n_k}(q_i)||+ ||\gamma_{n_k}(q_i)-\gamma_{n_k}(q_j)||+ ||\gamma_{n_k}(q_j)-\gamma(q_j)||\\
&\leq ||\gamma(q_i)-\gamma_{n_k}(q_i)|| + |q_i-q_j|L(\gamma_{n_k}) +||\gamma_{n_k}(q_j)-\gamma(q_j)||
\end{align}

Taking a limit as $k\rightarrow \infty$ implies that $||\gamma(q_i)-\gamma(q_j)|| \leq |q_i-q_j|\mu_{\epsilon}$.

Thus, we can extend $\gamma(q_i)$ to a continuous function $\gamma(t)$ over the reals $t \in [0,1]$.  With a little more work, we can show the same subsequence of functions $\gamma_{n_k}(t)$ indeed converge (pointwise for all $t \in [0,1]$) to $\gamma(t)$, and $\gamma(t)$ itself must satisfy for all $t, v \in [0,1]$:

$$ ||\gamma(t)-\gamma(v)|| \leq |t-v|\mu_{\epsilon} $$

It remains to show two properties: (i) $D_1(S) \subseteq D_1(\gamma)\subseteq \overline{D_{1+\epsilon}(S)}$, and (ii) $\gamma(t)$ is rectifiable with length that achieves the infimum $\mu_{\epsilon}$. The first property holds by Notes 2 and 3 below.  The second property holds because:  For any finite partition of times $0 \leq t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_N \leq 1$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^N||\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i-1})|| \leq \mu_{\epsilon}\sum_{i=1}^N|t_i-t_{i-1}| \leq \mu_{\epsilon}$ and so $\gamma$ is rectifiable with $L(\gamma) \leq \mu_{\epsilon}$.  But of course the first property then ensures $L(\gamma)\geq \mu_{\epsilon}$.  And so $\gamma$ achieves the infimum $\mu_{\epsilon}$.

---

Note 1: Proving $||\gamma_n(t)-\gamma_n(v)|| \leq |t-v|L(\gamma_n)$. Suppose that $v>t$, and the $\gamma_n(t)$ path has constant speed.  Then $\gamma_n(t)$ is the point on the path that is a fraction $t$ of the total distance, and $\gamma_n(v)$ is the point further along the path that is a fraction $v$ of the total distance.  So there is a path of length $(v-t)L(\gamma_n)$ between points $\gamma_n(t)$ and $\gamma_n(v)$, and this length must be greater than or equal to the length of the straight line between these points.

---

Note 2: Proof that $D_1(\gamma) \subseteq \overline{D_{1+\epsilon}(S)}$. Let $x \in D_1(\gamma)$.  Then there is a point $\gamma(t)$ (for some $t \in[0,1]$) such that $||\gamma(t)-x|| \leq 1$.  The sequence of points $\gamma_{n_k}(t)$ converges to $\gamma(t)$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.  However, $D_1(\gamma_{n_k})\subseteq\overline{D_{1+\epsilon}(S)}$ for all $k$, and so anything within radius 1 of $\gamma_{n_k}(t)$ is in $\overline{D_{1+\epsilon}(S)}$.  It follows that $x$ is arbitrarily close to points in the closed set $\overline{D_{1+\epsilon}(S)}$, so it must also be   in this set.

---

Note 3: Proof that $D_1(S) \subseteq D_1(\gamma)$.   Let $x \in D_1(S)$.  Then $x \in D_1(\gamma_{n_k})$ for every index $k$. So there are times $t_k \in [0,1]$ such that for all $k$ we have $||x - \gamma_{n_k}(t_k)|| \leq 1$. 
Choose a particular subsequence of indices $k(m)$ over which $t_{k(m)}$ converges (by Bolzano-Wierstrass) to a point $t \in[0,1]$.  So for any $m$:

\begin{align} 
||x - \gamma(t)|| &\leq ||x - \gamma_{n_{k(m)}}(t_{k(m)}) ||+ ||\gamma_{n_{k(m)}}(t_{k(m)})  - \gamma_{n_{k(m)}}(t)|| + ||\gamma_{n_{k(m)}}(t) - \gamma(t)|| \\
&\leq 1 + |t_{k(m)}-t|L(\gamma_{n_{k(m)}}) + ||\gamma_{n_{k(m)}}(t) - \gamma(t)||
\end{align}

Taking a limit as $m\rightarrow\infty$ gives $||x - \gamma(t)|| \leq 1$, and so $x \in D_1(\gamma)$.

---

Partial answer to question 2: The value $\lambda_0$ will exist whenever the set $S$ is convex with a rectifiable boundary, since scaled versions of convex sets “fit inside” each other like measuring cups. So we can take a path consisting of the boundary together with suitable reduced-scale versions of those (connected by short segments).

---

Possible counter-example showing infimum is not achievable when we use open-disc lawnmowers, i.e., using $E_1(\cdot)$:  Let $S$ be the closed disc of radius 1 about the origin.  Then $E_1(S)$ is the open disc of radius 2 about the origin. I believe $\lambda_0=2\pi$ (intuitive, but hard to prove rigorously), and this can be achieved arbitrarily closely by the path that consists of the unit circle about the origin, plus a small line segment of size $\epsilon$ starting from any point on the circle and moving inward to the origin (this line segment allows coverage of the origin itself).  The limit $\gamma$ of such paths (and I think the only possible candidate path that could achieve the infimum) is the unit circle itself.  But the origin is in $E_1(S)$ but *not* in $E_1(\gamma)$.  So $E_1(S)$ is *not* a subset of $E_1(\gamma)$, and the infimum is not achieved.  However, it *would* be achieved with a closed-disc lawnmower.

A simpler counter-example in the same spirit might be when $S$ is a closed square of side length 2.

---

Okay Mario's completion of the "lemon" example makes it obvious that $2\pi$ is the min.  Actually it is easy to show that any convex shape $S$ *must* include the boundary of $S$ in any path that covers $E_1(S)$ and for the $\epsilon=0$ case.  But I wonder if  $\lambda_{\epsilon}=\lambda_{0}$ in all those cases? (seems intuitively true if $S$ is the unit disc, but somehow not clear how to rigorously prove).

Comment: I've made some edits that were easier to apply directly than explain in a comment; please look over them and make sure I haven't misinterpreted anything.

Comment: Note that since the length of $\gamma$ is the supremum of $\sum_i||\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i+1})||$ over any sequence $0=t_0\le t_1\le\dots\le t_n=1$, your inequality at the end is indeed sufficient to deduce $L(\gamma)\le\lambda_\epsilon$. (I believe you, but could you put in a proof for the claimed inequality?)

Comment: Also, you cannot make the assumption that the $\gamma_n$ are piecewise linear at the start without more work - it doesn't follow from my proof. That said, it shouldn't matter to the proof, since it is sufficient that they are rectifiable and that follows from the assumption on lengths.

Comment: Furthermore, it doesn't look like anything in the proof requires that $\epsilon>0$, so if you add in the part of the proof showing that $E_1(S)\subseteq E_1(\gamma)\subseteq\overline{E_{1+\epsilon}(S)}$, I think this will generalize to "if $\lambda_0$ exists, then it is a minimum" as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  I added piecewise linear later since I (incorrectly) assumed it follows from your proof (you are right it does not) and I also was unsure about defining "constant speed" for a general non-polygonal path.

Comment: Any rectifiable path can be converted to a constant-speed path, because the function $t\mapsto L(\gamma[0,t])$ that measures the length of an initial segment of $\gamma$ is a weakly increasing continuous function, so you can invert it to find the smallest $t$ that gives you a path with the desired length.

Comment: I could not prove $E_1(S)\subseteq E_1(\gamma)$, so I give a possible counter-example to achievability of the infimum, and a proof of achievability for a re-defined lawnmower with a closed disc.

Comment: Very nice. My idea with the subset-of-closure thing was to "ignore boundary effects", but I see it wasn't sufficient to just take the interior and closure (I would take $D_1(S)^\circ$ instead of $D_1(S)$ in the definition of $\mu_\epsilon$). Perhaps a more durable requirement is "$E_1(S)\setminus E_1(\gamma)$ has empty interior".

Comment: A proof of $\lambda_0=2\pi$: your sequence shows $\lambda_0\le 2\pi$. For the converse, note that in order to cover the points at $r=2-\epsilon$, and some $\theta$, the center must be in a small lemon-shaped region around $r=1$ and the same $\theta$, so by choosing $\theta=2\pi/n$ and $\epsilon$ sufficiently small w.r.t $n$, you can force the lawnmower to visit the points on a regular $n$-gon within some $\epsilon$. And accepting that the edges of an $n$-gon solve the associated TSP problem...

Comment: An extension to your attempt at part 2: If $S$ has rectifiable boundary $\gamma$, then let $T=E_1(S)\setminus E_1(\gamma_1)$ and $\{C_n\}$ be the connected components of $E_{1/2}(T)$ (there are finitely many because each has area $\ge\pi/4$). Now $E_2(T)\subseteq E_1(S)$, and each $E_1(C_n)$ has a $\gamma_n$ that covers it with overspill $1/2$, which can be connected to the main path by picking a point in $C_n\setminus T$ (which is nonempty) and drawing a straight line from the point on $\gamma_n$ to the one on $\gamma$ that covers this point.

Comment: It only remains to prove that $E_{-1}(E_1(S))$ has rectifiable boundary for any bounded $S$ to finish part 2 (which I think is true, since the shape of such regions is restricted from being too "wiggly" in one direction, which should eliminate most kinds of non-rectifiability).

Comment: Okay, I think I agree with your argument for part 2, which is very nice: This shows that if $S$ has a connected and rectifiable boundary then $\lambda_0$ exists. I guess if $S$ is path connected with a finite number of connected boundary parts, then we can connect them via curves that do not leave $S$.

Comment: Somehow my brain is slow.  Your converse "lemon" example is obvious in retrospect if you also consider the fact that you cannot go beyond the disc of size 2 (a constraint of course for the $\epsilon=0$ case).  What was not obvious to me, but which seems intuitively clear, is if the unit circle (plus a tiny segment more for the origin) is optimal for covering the 2-radius disc, regardless of $\epsilon$ (so we do not care about overspill).

Comment: I've posted the missing pieces to the proof of part 2 as a [separate question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068117).

Comment: Well, I see you edited your question to change the definition of $\lambda_{\epsilon}$ from using $E_1(\gamma)$ to using $\overline{E_1(\gamma)}$, which makes my original achievability proof work without using closed-disc mowers. But I _like_ closed-disc mowers!  =)  The change also makes the counter-example discussion (above) confusing to new readers.

Comment: The change to use $\overline{E_1}$ is effectively the same as using closed-disc mowers, but I prefer keeping the base definition using $E_x$ instead of $D_x$ because open sets behave better under arbitrary union than closed sets - $E_1$ can be described as a union of open unit balls, while $D_1$ cannot be described as a union of closed balls. The reason for the modification is because I would prefer to the question and answer to maintain the same set of definitions; if you want to keep your counterexample, add a blurb about why an open ball definition wouldn't work.