# Is It Always Possible to Draw A Connected Compact Set in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1169447/174927), I wondered whether a printer could render all continuous functions "well enough". In particular, I am curious about the following statement:

> Let $S$ be a compact, connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$. For any $\varepsilon>0$ define $$S_{\varepsilon}=\bigcup_{s\in S}B(s,\varepsilon)$$ where $B(s,\varepsilon)$ ithe ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around $s$ (under the usual metric) - that is $S_{\varepsilon}$ is $S$ "expanded" everywhere by $\varepsilon$. For all $S$ and $\varepsilon$, must there exist a curve $\gamma:\mathbb [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ of finite length such that $$S_{\varepsilon}=\bigcup_{x\in[0,1]}B(\gamma(x),\varepsilon)$$

Or, putting it informally:

> Given a compact, connected set, is it possible for a printer, which always draws a swath of radius $\varepsilon$, to render the set as closely as possible?

My thinking is "yes", because, we can clearly do this if we allow any sloppiness -that is, if we don't care whether the the points within some $0<\varepsilon'$ of the boundary of $S_{\varepsilon}$ are covered. Hopefully, complex figures on the boundary will be swallowed up when we expand out the set $S$ - but I'm suspicious of pathological examples and can't seem to draw up a proof or counterexample.

---

A statement I believe is equivalent (and of which equivalence I believe a simple proof likely exists) is the following:

> Define $F_{\varepsilon}(S)$ to be the "inflation" of $S$ by $\varepsilon$ - the set of points within $\varepsilon$ of some $s\in S$. Define $f_{\varepsilon}(S)$ to be the "deflation" of $S$ by $\varepsilon$ - the set of points $s\in S$ such that the ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around is contained in $S$. Then, we wish to show that the boundary of $f_{\varepsilon}(F_{\varepsilon}(S))$ has finite length for any compact $S$.

Comment: There are some theorems about tubular neighborhoods of compact manifolds that seem relevant to your question, but I can’t find any clear statement just for $\mathbb{R}^2$. What you seem to be wanting is that the tubular neighborhood of any compact connected region is the tubular neighborhood of a curve. I’m no expert, but maybe that idea will give you a lead.

Comment: The existence of such a $\gamma$ of finite length of the "thickening" of the set amounts to requiring the set to be pathwise connected, no?

Comment: @Uzman I don't believe the set being pathwise connected is not necessary (I'm fairly certain that this is possible for the topologist's sine curve) - certainly the expanded set must be pathwise connected, but expanding any connected set yields a pathwise connected one. The converse of whether pathwise connected is sufficient is more or less what this question asks - a pathwise connected space could have a non-rectifiable boundary, so it's not obvious that this property must hold.

Comment: @Meelo Possibly an extra negation in the first sentence of your comment? I had thought of the sine curve at first as well, and indeed the result holds for it (since you don't require $\gamma([0,1])=S$).

Comment: @Uzman Yeah; feel free to ignore either "don't" or "not" in the first sentence - they're not both supposed to be there.

Comment: I have three concerns: 1. Since we are talking about the length of the curve, $\gamma$ should at least be $C^1$; 2. Why would we consider one epsilon for both the set and the curve? (I believe these two points may introduce technical complications); 3. Why would we consider the whole cover of the set instead of using its compactness, and consequently set the curve to pass through the centers of the finitely many balls (here again smoothness is an issue even though we need not two different epsilons)?

Comment: @Uzman $\gamma$ doesn't need to be continuously differentiable; we can assume it is Lipschitz continuous, though. The single $\varepsilon$ is, in a sense, the "universal" case - expanding the set more than the curve is equivalent to expanding the set some, then expanding both set and curve equally (and expanding the curve more is clearly not generally workable - i.e. if the set was a point). And the $S_{\varepsilon}$ are not compact and the cover I write out for them will not have a finite subcover if $S$ has more than one point.

Comment: Also I was thinking whether it is a good idea to formalize the process of printing as finding a curve with error, because as far as I know (which is not so far) digital printing is more of a 'coloring squares', in which case using a concept like box counting might be better. In light of this, I would be wary of fractals for counterexamples. Though I too think the answer to your question is affirmative.

Comment: Indeed the cover is not compact but what I am saying is why do we consider the whole cover while we can consider a finite subcover of it (that covers $S$)?

Comment: @Uzman I think I see what you're saying - yes, there are other reasonable ways to formalize a question about printing. But, I'm much more interested in mathematics than printers, and found this particular formulation most intriguing, even if it's somewhat unnatural.

Comment: Seems related to this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785670/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-mow-a-lawn/1064582#1064582 Mario's proof in this link can be modified to show existence of a finite length path $\gamma(x) \in S_{\epsilon}$ that satisfies $S \subseteq \cup_{x \in [0,1]} B(\gamma(x),\epsilon)\subseteq S_{2\epsilon}$.  I think this is "good enough" for a printer.

Comment: This probably doesn't help answer the question, but your $f_\epsilon\circ F_\epsilon$ is known as [closing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)) in image processing.

Comment: $f_{\epsilon}(F_{\epsilon}(S))$ seems the same as the complement of the inflation of the complement of the inflation of S(kind of like de Morgan laws).Thus,it would be enough to prove that if F is the inflation of any plane continuum then Bd F could be represented as finite-lenght curves(this is stronger than what you need but might be true).It seems Bd F would be piece-wise differentiable with bounded curvature.This gives a sketch how to obtain a curve(s),but it may cover only part of the original set,but one would need to repeat the procedure only finitely many times,like onion from outside

Comment: I believe my previous sketch might work, though Bd F might have countably many (rather than just finitely many) differentiable pieces. I first tried a counterexample yesterday, didnt work, here is the idea. Let I=[0,1] and X=KxI for a continuum K contained in I. For example K may be a sequence converging (very slowly) to 0. Then there will be many ups and downs in Bd inflation X which I hoped would imply the curve has infinite length but it doesnt. I looked at X=KxI with K a Cantor set, the curve has a finite length. Two types of points on Bd: With a unique ball, and with more that one ball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof that the boundary of $f_\epsilon(F_\epsilon(S))$ does have finite length for each $\epsilon > 0$. I'll use the following inequality for any compact $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$,
\begin{align}
{\rm perimeter}(F_\epsilon(S))\le \frac2\epsilon{\rm area}(F_\epsilon(S)).&&{\rm(1)}
\end{align}
More on why this holds in a bit. First, I'll use it to prove the result asked for. Note that $f_\epsilon(S)$ is the set of points of distance at least distance $\epsilon$ from the complement of $S$ and, hence,
$$
\partial f_\epsilon(S)=\partial F_\epsilon(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus S),
$$
where $\partial S$ denotes the boundary of a set $S$.
So,
$$
\partial f_\epsilon(F_\epsilon(S))=\partial F_\epsilon(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus F_\epsilon(S)).
$$
Now, if $S$ is contained in the closed ball $\bar B_R$ of radius $R$ about the origin, then $F_\epsilon(S)$ is contained in $\bar B_{R+\epsilon}$ giving,
$$
\partial F_\epsilon(\bar B_{R+\epsilon}\setminus F_\epsilon(S))=\partial\bar B_{R+2\epsilon}\cup\partial F_\epsilon(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus F_\epsilon(S))=\partial\bar B_{R+2\epsilon}\cup\partial f_\epsilon(F_\epsilon(S)).
$$
Putting this together with (1),
\begin{align}
{\rm perimeter}(f_\epsilon(F_\epsilon(S)))&={\rm perimeter}(F_\epsilon(\bar B_{R+\epsilon}\setminus F_\epsilon(S)))-{\rm perimeter}(\bar B_{R+2\epsilon})\\
&\le\frac2\epsilon{\rm area}(F_\epsilon(\bar B_{R+\epsilon}))\\
&=\frac2\epsilon\pi(R+2\epsilon)^2 < \infty,
\end{align}
which concludes the proof.

---

Let me now show why (1) holds. There is a quick proof for $S$ a finite set, as given by Theorem 5.3 in the [PhD thesis by Zoltán Gyenes](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~dom/z.pdf). By compactness, for any $\delta > 0$, there exists a finite subset $A$ of $S$ such that $F_{\epsilon}(A)\supset F_{\epsilon-\delta}(S)$, so the boundary of $F_{\epsilon}(S)$ lies within a distance $\delta$ of the boundary of $F_\epsilon(A)$. Fixing $N$ points around the boundary of $F_\epsilon(S)$, these points all lie within $\delta$ of points on the boundary of $F_\epsilon(A)$ so, the length of the piecewise linear curve interpolating these points is bounded by
\begin{align}
N(2\delta)+{\rm perimeter}F_\epsilon(A)&\le 2 N\delta+\frac2{\epsilon}{\rm area}F_\epsilon(A)\\
&\le 2 N\delta+\frac2\epsilon{\rm area}F_\epsilon(S)
\end{align}
Letting $N$ go to infinity gives (1) for the compact set $S$.